# Current mirrors with the voltage amplifiers

Tags: transistors, gain, common-emitter, current-mirror

I am having a slight confusion with the current mirrors and their use with the common emitter amplifier. I have seen that the current mirrors can be used to bias the circuits and replace the need for the resistors for biasing the gate. Consider the circuit below having a gain of approximately Vout/Vin~=R2/R1=7. The circuit works perfectly fine in this case but I want to use current mirrors with the circuit and eliminate the resistors which are used.

1. Is it possible to do that in the circuit below? If it is, can someone help to make its circuit?

   [image]
2. In my opinion I should keep this circuit the same and move the current mirror part to the high side in order to increase the impedance and make it a better current source, and amplifier, as shown. Is this configuration written? Kindly help me with this.

   [image]

The above circuit is just a rough sketch I want to say. This is not amplifying my circuit.

My purpose is to use the current mirrors for biasing in the voltage amplifier.

Comment: But what is the point of using the current mirror in CE amplifier? Also, the circuit you have shown has not nothing to do with the current mirror.

Comment: Basically Just want to check If I could use biasing and make a cascoded voltage amplifier. Cascoded one needed biasing and I want to bias using current mirror as Ive read that current mirror can Bias trasistors.

Comment: You haven't drawn a current mirror here.

Comment: The second image has a current mirror like circuit at the high side.

Comment: @kam1212 No, it does not. Where's the diode-connected BJT, for example? Or, perhaps better still, please provide some analysis that shows a current mirror behavior. I'd like to see it.